# Why is my HFS+ filesystem not read-write, despite my fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a disk that I used to use on my mac, but now I use it only on Ubuntu 16.04.2. I have a directory /movies that I think should be mounting Read/Write but is actually mounting Read Only on every reboot.
The /etc/fstab entry is:

`UUID=f587dbf5-7bb9-3412-93f2-4f418e067cf1 /movies hfsplus force,rw,auto,user 0 0`

What else do I need to check?

Answer (score 9):

What I needed to check was `dmesg` where I would have learned that

`hfsplus: Filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  mounting read-only.`

Probably a result of a recent power outage.
Unmounting the drive, running `sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdc2` to reset a flag, and afterward `sudo mount /movies` re-mounted the drive read-write, per the configuration in /etc/fstab.

Comment: This has happened to me twice now with a Linux server where half the drives are HFS+ (to support Macs) and half are ext4. The HFS+ formatted partitions are the only ones ever effected so I'm beginning to think this filesystem is particularly sensitive to not being unmounted properly.

Comment: Yes. I have noticed that a reboot fixes them. But that's not the Linux/Unix way.