# How to mount an external hard drive as HFS+ by default?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I just switched from MacOs to Ubuntu 21.10.
I use an external HFS+ hard drive to share files between MacOs and Ubuntu.

To enable read / write on this disk from ubuntu, I have to mount it with [hfsprogs](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/hfsprogs) as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/365270/264961):

```bsh
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdx# /mount/point
```

Every time I restart the computer, I have to force remount the disk again (so, I made a shell script to run after boot).

Is there a way to auto mount this disk as HFS+ on startup?

Comment: You should be able to configure `udisks` to use the right options for your specific drive. Or add an entry to the `/etc/fstabs` file. See [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions).

Answer (score 3):

To auto mount a disk append a line in /etc/fstab :

```
PARTUUID=[a-letter-digit-hypen-code] /mount/point hfsplus defaults 0 0
```

I am not sure about "hfsplus" but I take it from your question.
An example to get the [a-letter-digit-hypen-code]:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdx1
```

/dev/sdx1 from the example is retrieved from:

```
sudo fdisk -l           #lsblk is also enough here
```

But sda,sdb,sdc are the most common values and 1 stands for the first partition in most cases.

Edit:
I tested with UUID instead of PARTUUID and is ok. PART means PARTITION.
Then, another example is:

```
UUID=... /media/user/disk auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: Why do you recommend PARTUID instead of UUID? I am used to seeing the latter in fstab. I like `lsblk` instead of `fdisk` for this purpose - the output is easier to understand and `sudo` is not required. Note that disks may have different codes than `sdx` depending on the type of partitioning and so on.

Comment: I think UUID is ok too. PART stands for partition. Note: In my external disk drive it has 36 chars I don't think it is a rule.

Comment: UUID and PARTUID are different things. PARTUID is valid with GPT partitions. Either will work on a GPT partition. To the best of my knowledge UUID will work on anything.

Comment: This won't work if the filesystem has been uncleanly unmounted, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/922204/why-is-my-hfs-filesystem-not-read-write-despite-my-fstab